# How to add a check constraint on column for update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, h2

I'm adding a column to a table, and want to set a constraint on it, that it's not allowed to be updated until a given date, stored in the same table row.

This is what I've got so far:

```
ALTER TABLE sometable 
    ADD somecolumn BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

ALTER TABLE sometable 
    ADD CONSTRAINT somedate_before_now 
        CHECK (somedatecolumn < GETDATE());
```

How do I get this to work, for updates of `somecolumn` only? Inserts and updates of other columns should be allowed.

I'm testing this on an in memory H2 database, but it will have to work with SQL Server as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the safe way to do this is using a trigger.

A constraint such as this:

```
CHECK (somedatecolumn < GETDATE())
```

doesn't really make sense from a relational point of view.  It can guarantee the values are true on an `update` or `insert`.  However, the database cannot guarantee that the values are true in general.  You should use `CHECK` constraints for things that you always want to be true in a row.

(The problem is that `GETDATE()` changes with no changes on the row.)

Comment: I agree. not only that, but the OP wants this to work only for updates so a check constrain can't be the correct way. an instead of update trigger is what I would choose.

Comment: Thank you. To be honest I don't know much about triggers, so I really can't say if this will work for validation of my column, but I see your point about GETDATE().

I've added the validation into my services for now.